# VS2010 - Using <Import /> to share properties between setup projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, wix

Why doesn't it work to `<Import />` this file, when it works when I replace the  statement with just copy-pasting the three properties?

**../../Setup.Version.proj**

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <InstallerMajorVersion>7</InstallerMajorVersion>
        <InstallerMinorVersion>7</InstallerMinorVersion>
        <InstallerBuildNumber>7</InstallerBuildNumber>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Works:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <InstallerMajorVersion>7</InstallerMajorVersion>
        <InstallerMinorVersion>7</InstallerMinorVersion>
        <InstallerBuildNumber>7</InstallerBuildNumber>
        <OutputName>asdf-$(InstallerMajorVersion).$(InstallerMinorVersion).$(InstallerBuildNumber)</OutputName>
        <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="../../Setup.Version.proj" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputName>asdf-$(InstallerMajorVersion).$(InstallerMinorVersion).$(InstallerBuildNumber)</OutputName>
        <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
```

Here the variables just evaulate to empty strings... :( I'm certain the path to the imported project is correct.

---

### **So it seems to work fine when i run msbuild from the command line, but not when I build the project inside Visual Studio. Why in the world?**

Comment: Should be ok - try correct slashes "..\..\Se..." and see if MSBuild produces any kind of warnings.

Comment: Don't know. Note: your question seem to be missing actual message for "same error".

Comment: It's just an error related to the variables not being set. If I paste them the error goes away and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it didn't work is that Visual Studio had cached the included file, so that any changes I made to it didn't take effect until I reloaded the solution or restarted Visual Studio. This seems to be a limitation of VS 2010. After reloading VS 2010, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to reproduce and everything works:

**importme.proj**

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <InstallerMajorVersion>7</InstallerMajorVersion>
        <InstallerMinorVersion>7</InstallerMinorVersion>
        <InstallerBuildNumber>7</InstallerBuildNumber>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**main.proj**

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="importme.proj" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputName>asdf-$(InstallerMajorVersion).$(InstallerMinorVersion).$(InstallerBuildNumber)</OutputName>
        <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="Build">
        <Message Text="$(OutputName)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17626
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.17626]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 10.09.2012 12:35:12.
Project "d:\temp\SO\main.proj" on node 1 (default targets).
Build:
  asdf-7.7.7
Done Building Project "d:\temp\SO\main.proj" (default targets).


Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.55
```

**Run using**

```
msbuild main.proj
```

**UPDATE**: You need to reload project for Include'd files to be updated or use [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919204/how-to-turn-off-caching-of-build-definitions-in-visual-studio/6217800).

Comment: Aha!! It works from the command line for me too, but not from Visual studio! Why in the world?

Comment: Do you have any conditions on element such as configuration|platform? May be they are different between console and VS?

Comment: On which element? What I have pasted is exactly how it looks here.

Comment: Try to put `<PropertyGroup>` into `<Target Name="BeforeBuild">`

Comment: Sorry, what? Just an empty <PropertyGroup>, or? I don't understand :P

Comment: No no, that one with `<OutputName>asdf-$(InstallerMajorVersion).$(InstallerMinorVersion).$(InstallerBuildNumber)</OutputName>` inside

Comment: I can't move everything into the BeforeBuild... Only moving OutputName didnt work either, because then OutputName didn't exist where I referred to it.

Comment: Can you run msbuild not on vcproj but on sln to see what will be the result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16492/discussion-between-pavel-krymets-and-arex1337)

Answer (score 0):

The [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) element is only valid under the `Project` element. However, the code appears to want to import the values into a `<ProjectGroup>` element. Try declaring the values as variables in Setup.Version.proj and reference them in your main MSBuild file, such as:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="../../Setup.Version.proj" /> <!-- Variables declared in here -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <InstallerMajorVersion>$(MyInstallerMajorVersion)</InstallerMajorVersion>
        <InstallerMinorVersion>$(MyInstallerMinorVersion)</InstallerMinorVersion>
        <InstallerBuildNumber>$(MyInstallerBuildNumber)</InstallerBuildNumber>
        <OutputName>asdf-$(InstallerMajorVersion).$(InstallerMinorVersion).$(InstallerBuildNumber)</OutputName>
        <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
```

Comment: Darn, they're still not defined. I can't find any good examples of this online either...

Comment: @arex1337 Can you post the contents of your Setup.Version.proj file, please?

Comment: @arex1337 Hmm. The only thing I can think of is perhaps order of operations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171464.aspx). If I think of anything else, I'll let you know.

Comment: In Setup.Version.proj you define

    `<InstallerMajorVersion>7</InstallerMajorVersion>`

However in your main project file you reference

    `$(MyInstallerMajorVersion)`

Try fixing Setup.Version.proj and see what happens.

Comment: I think you may have mistaken one of the answers for my question. I don't reference $(MyInstallerMajorVersion). I did try akton's suggestion too, without any success.