# How do you share properties/variables between multiple projects while being able to edit them in one place?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, wix

Currently I have this in multiple projects:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <InstallerMajorVersion>1</InstallerMajorVersion>
    <InstallerMinorVersion>09</InstallerMinorVersion>
    <InstallerBuildVersion>08</InstallerBuildVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
...
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputName>Project-$(InstallerMajorVersion).$(InstallerMinorVersion).$(InstallerBuildVersion)</OutputName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'd like to have this information (the first PropertyGroup) in only one file, so I don't have to edit it in multiple places. However I need to import or somehow get to this information from every project file so I can set OutputName correctly.

How do you share properties/variables between multiple projects?

I didn't have much luck with my `<Import />` approach: [VS2010 - Using <Import /> to share properties between setup projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325072/vs2010-using-import-to-share-properties-between-setup-projects)

Comment: You share properties between multiple projects using Import. If Import is not working for you then post more information about how you are using Import and what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works using Import. I just had problems with VS2010 caching. See the linked issue for more details.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an altogether separate project just for loading this configuration stuff, and compiling it as a separate library / DLL? You could then use that DLL in each of the other projects where you need to import these settings.