# Import .target file could not dynamic loading to my project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a .target file, which imports to my project:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="CreateInstaller">    
  <Import Project="$(PathToTargetFile)\My.target" />
<Project>
```

The .target is build by another target:

```
  <Target Name="MyCustomTarget" DependsOnTargets="$(OtherTargets)">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(PathToTargetFile)\My.target" />
  </Target>
```

The target `MyCustomTarget` is called several time, each time the content of `My.target` would be changed. But `My.target` seems that not imported anymore rather than the first time. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to resolve this problem?

Visual Studio caches all imported .target files. That is the reason why you `My.target` seems that not imported anymore rather than the first time.

To resolve this issue, you can use a temp `.target` file with different name, this will force VS to reload `.target` file:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TempProjectFile>My.$([System.Guid]::NewGuid()).target</TempProjectFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="My.target" DestinationFiles="$(TempProjectFile)" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(TempProjectFile)" />
    <Delete Files="@(TempProjectFile)" />
  </Target>
```

You can refer to [the similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919204/how-to-turn-off-caching-of-build-definitions-in-visual-studio) for detail info.

Hope this help you.