# Dynamically update .csproj during Visual Studio build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-generation

We have a very complicated multi-stage build system:

1. Auto-generate a ton of C# from XML.
2. Compile C# with Visual Studio.
3. Post-compile non-Microsoft-native languages like Sass and JavaScript.
4. (*...more steps for database-oriented things...*)

Importantly, in the first stage, a set of short XML files are transformed into C# files.  Various .csproj files are automatically updated to add any new C# files that were generated, and to remove any C# files that are no longer relevant.

This has been the way our software has been built for many, many years, and it has been a big, big win for us.  More than a million lines of our code are automatically generated from only a few thousand lines of XML: Our overall design of using custom code generators definitely isn't going to change!

---

However, the code-generation process lives *outside* Visual Studio, as a manual step.  We'd really like to integrate the code-generation process into the standard Visual Studio build.

Our plan was to have the code generation run as a pre-build event on an otherwise-empty .csproj file, and it would generate the *next* .csproj file before Visual Studio had a chance to get to it (using Dependencies to control build order).

Unfortunately, Visual Studio's build-caching logic defeats this:  **One .csproj apparently can't modify another .csproj file during the build, because Visual Studio caches the second .csproj file's contents.**

Visual Studio complains loudly if you try, with delightful inscrutable error messages and general glitchiness.

---

So is there a way around this?  **Is there a way to have substantial C# code generation as part of a Visual Studio build?**

Or are we stuck with having it as a separate, manual process outside Visual Studio?

Comment: You might be able to [disable the caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903803/how-can-i-prevent-external-msbuild-files-from-being-cached-by-visual-studio-du) and have things work like you want.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that's a little sturdier than "maybe you could try" answers.  I've experimented with the answer at that link, and a few others that I found on StackOverflow, and none that I've found seem to work well enough to be usable for us.

Comment: How about, after generation, an nmake project in your (parent) solution executes msbuild on  the distinct (child) solution/project that you generated?

Comment: The .csproj and .cs files are not _fully_ generated; some are created manually, and the code generator updates and adds files as necessary. (The .cs files make heavy use of `partial` classes, and our programmers know not to edit anything with a `.generated.cs` extension.)  So the .csproj and .cs files can't exist fully outside Visual Studio either, just managed by `msbuild` and `nmake`; they have to be normally-editable as part of the Solution too.

Comment: msbuild can build visual studio projects.  So I think you could still have a distinct child project/solution containing some generated and some manual content, which you kick off after generating in a parent solution.  I realize two VS solutions isn't as great as one.